# adb: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted

Tags: android, adb, react-native

```
info 
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 331.02 MB / 11.63 GB
      Shell: 5.4.2 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 8.10.0 - /usr/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.16.0 - /usr/bin/yarn
      npm: 3.5.2 - /usr/bin/npm
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.8 => 0.59.8 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

running `react-native run-android` the packager stops and get this error:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
181 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 179 up-to-date
info Running adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
adb: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted
info Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
info Starting the app on emulator-5554 (adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.linkapverypurenative/com.linkapverypurenative.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.linkapverypurenative/.MainActivity }
```

I can run this project on another Ubuntu without any problem. However on this new installation of Ubuntu I get this error.

[image]